# Calling MongoImport From Java

Tags: java, shell, mongoimport

I have written a .bat file *(as I am testing on Windows for now)*:-

  `echo Program Starts
  mongoimport.exe --host 127.0.0.1 -d myDB -c things --type csv --file 
  D:\MOCK_DATA.csv --fields id,Name.f_name,Name.l_name,email,gender
  echo Program Ends`

- I kept the .bat file in /bin folder of MongoDB.
- The .bat file works fine if I call it directly from Windows Command Prompt.
- But when I call the .bat file using Java Program, the mongoImport doesn't
  run. The program doesn't give any errors also. Here's my Java Program:-

       `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("Path to my .bat File");
       Process process = pb.start();
       BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       String line = null;
       while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
             builder.append(line);
             builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
       }
      return builder.toString();`

Following is the Java Console output:

`echo Program Starts 
Program Starts
mongoimport.exe --host 127.0.0.1 -d myDB -c things --type csv --file D:\MOCK_DATA.csv --fields id,Name.f_name,Name.l_name,email,gender 
echo Program Ends 
Program Ends`

Answer (score 0):

```
I found the solution to the problem. Following lines helped in identifying the error:-
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
pb.redirectOutput(new File("D:\\output.txt"));

The issue was that I didn't set the 'directory' where .bat file commands will run.
pb.directory(new File("\\MongoDB\\Server\\3.2\\bin"));
```